# What web application will receive an SMS/MMS image from a phone and display it in the website?

Tags: webapp-rec, images

I want to find a web application that I can setup a SMS number in it, and people can send images through SMS, MMS or email, and they will be presented in a slide show.

Use Case:

1. I setup the web application and a SMS number and email is assigned to me
2. Any user with the SMS number or email sends pictures to SMS number or email
3. Web application receives picture and display it as part of the slide show of other pictures (clarification, the web application will not be refreshed, so there has to be some kind of JavaScript for it)
4. repeat until finish

Comment: Isn't SMS text only (max 140 chars). Afaik MMS is for images?

Answer (score 0):

Check **[Photobucket Mobile](http://photobucket.com/mobile/index/)**. From their website:

> Upload photos and videos to
>   Photobucket using mobile email or
>   picture/video messaging
>
> Upload images & videos via email to
>   Photobucket
>
> Photobucket is the premier destination
>   for uploading, sharing, linking and
>   finding photos, videos and graphics.
>   Host all your images and videos for
>   free, then share them by email or on
>   social sites like Facebook, Twitter
>   and MySpace. Search for videos and
>   images in Photobucket's huge library.
>   Edit your uploaded photos with our
>   feature-rich photo editor. Make
>   slideshows to share with friends.
>   Plus, access your albums on your
>   mobile using the mobile site or one of
>   our smart phone apps

Answer (score 0):

I've emailed photos to my [private Flickr email address](http://www.flickr.com/help/photos/?search=upload+email+address#16) and had them display automatically on my photostream.  Their FAQs say that it is also possible to [post photos to your blog](http://www.flickr.com/help/account/#47) automatically.